# Database relation design and laravel eloquent

Tags: mysql, database, relational-database, laravel-5.3, eloquent

I'm bit confuse in database relations.I'm using laravel and need a good practice of relations . I have four tables teachers , classes ,sections and subjects .So teacher teaches multiple classes of multiple subjects in multiple sections.
e.g

```
teacher1 teaches class9 of subject English in section A and B
teacher1 teaches class9 of subject Math in section A 
teacher1 teaches class9 of subject Chemistry in section A and b

teacher2 teaches class9 of subject English in section A and B
teacher2 teaches class9 of subject Math in section A 
teacher2 teaches class9 of subject Chemistry in section A and b

teacher2 teaches class10 of subject English in section A and B
teacher2 teaches class10 of subject Math in section A 
teacher2 teaches class10 of subject chemistry in section A and c
```

So this is my scenario i have four tables without relation like teachers with records of teacher , classes with records class like 10th , 9th etc ,subjects with records like English , Math etc and sections like A ,B , C etc.
So what are the best practices of creating relationship between these tables and how could used eloquent relation in laravel.

[image]

This is my ER diagram.Is it correct design if yes then how could create eloquent relationship in laravel?

Comment: What is a "section"?

Comment: Section means subdivision of class like class 10th and sub part of this class are  A (10th A) , B(10th B)

Comment: Can you show the schema structure for the tables i.e. the columns that the tables have?

Comment: Please don't confuse "relation", which refers to a mathematical structure associating sets of values (and represented by tables in SQL databases) with "relationships" in a network data model (the data model implemented by object-relational mappers).

Comment: u can use a normal pivot table with extra columns. in the pivot table you will save the subject id, the teacher id and the section. and you can access that table like every other pivot table through eloquent relationships.